# How do I combine three bulma css classes into one using less or any other option?

Tags: css, sass, less, bulma

I have the following bulma classes to be applied one div

```
"box", "has-text-weight-semibold", "has-text-link-dark", "has-background-primary-light"
```

How do I convert into one single class "custom_class" ?